# How to fix sharing violation exception in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a signature pad in my application. I am copying the saved image to another path because I don't know how to get the file path of the signature. I am using

> xamarin.controls.signaturepad.forms

Here's how I do it:

```
var cafNo = CafNo.Text;
var signatureFile = cafNo + "_signature.png";

Stream sigimage = await Signature.GetImageStreamAsync(SignaturePad.Forms.SignatureImageFormat.Png);

string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), signatureFile);
SignatureFile.Text = fileName;

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    await sigimage.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```

And here is where I get the violation error:

```
if (!signaturepathdoesExist || string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature))
{
    signaturepath = null;
}
else
{
    signaturepath = File.ReadAllBytes(signature);
}
```

When I use File.ReadAllBytes I am getting the violation error.

How can I avoid and fix this?

Comment: have you set file read and write permissions in manifest? If no then add it, still doest work check out adding File Provider into android application

Comment: @Prateek I have added it

Comment: What is `signature` in your second code snippet？

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT the file path of the signature image that I copied

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes will return `A byte array containing the contents of the file`. Is that you want? Is signature the right path?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes, but the problem is when I use File.ReadAllBytes(signature); I am getting the error.